# Move unallocated space into extended partition to expand logical volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot setup with Fedora and Windows. For personal reasons, I have uninstalled Windows and would like to use the freed-up space to expand my Fedora partition (which is on a logical partition inside an extended partition).

I am using GParted on Fedora to manage my partitions.[image: disk partitions]

The 66.90GiB unallocated space is where Windows used to be. I am trying to move that space into the extended partition (/dev/sda4) and eventually merge it with /dev/sda6, but GParted does not allow me move/resize the extended partition to make use of the free space. I read that

> In Disk Management, unpartitioned space in primary partition area is called unallocated space, while unpartitioned space in extended partition area is named free space; unallocated can’t be used to extend to or create logical partition, and free space can’t be used to enlarge to or create primary partition. 
>   (*Source: https://www.partitionwizard.com/convertpartition/primary-partition-vs-logical-drive.html*)

I'm not sure how true the above statement is, because people seem to have done it or somehow worked around the issue. I have looked at several questions on StackExchange including:

- [cannot add unallocated space to extended partition using gparted](https://superuser.com/questions/312187/cannot-add-unallocated-space-to-extended-partition-using-gparted)
- [Extend logical partition with unallocated space](https://superuser.com/questions/645229/extend-logical-partition-with-unallocated-space)
- [Gparted cannot resize extended or LVM partition](https://superuser.com/questions/917988/gparted-cannot-resize-extended-or-lvm-partition?rq=1) (similar, but I'm not able to deactivate my logical partition because *fedora/swap is in use*)
- [What is the best way to add unallocated space located before to Ubuntu 12.04 partition with GParted live?](https://superuser.com/questions/729251/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-unallocated-space-located-before-to-ubuntu-12-04-par)
- [Add unallocated space to lvm](https://superuser.com/questions/129465/add-unallocated-space-to-lvm)
- and more

but I'm not sure if they're completely applicable here.

**So my question is**: how do I move the unallocated space into the extended partition to merge it with the fedora logical partition?

Any help would be appreciated!

**Extra Info:**

- My computer uses MBR and not GPT, so I am only allowed 4 primary partitions, if that's relevant.
- I can freely move/resize /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda6 around *inside* the extended partition, but I cannot move/resize the extended partition iteslf.

lsblk output

[image: lsblk output]

parted -l output

[image: parted -l output]

fdisk -l output
[image: fdisk -l output]

Comment: Are you using the installed Fedora system or an external Live Boot disc? You should be using the latter.

Comment: Why not just create a new PV in /dev/sda2 and add it to the VG?

Comment: @AFH I was using a Live USB! Anyway, I've just solved it. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm a bit new to this, didn't realize I could do that!

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten that Live Boot discs will use a swap partition if it finds it on the hard disc. I should have thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it, and I'll post the answer here in case someone else faces a similar problem.

I was unable to resize the partition because my swap space was still in use, so I found out I could disable it using `swapoff -a`.

After doing this, GParted allowed me to merge the unallocated space with the fedora logical partition. I then right clicked on the logical partition and selected the `Check` option.

Finally, I used the following to actually allocate the free space to the root and home partitions:

```
lvextend -L +20G /dev/fedora/home
lvextend -L +20G /dev/fedora/root
resize2fs /dev/fedora/home
resize2fs /dev/fedora/root
```